# Is there a way to share version variable across root Build.gradle and Settings.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I have `compose_version` from the Root project `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0'
    }
    //... some other codes
}
```

In my `settings.gradle`, I use the latest catalog feature as below

```
    versionCatalogs {
        composeLibs {
            version('compose_version', $compose_version)
            alias('ui-core').to('androidx.compose.ui', 'ui').versionRef('compose_version')
            alias('material').to('androidx.compose.material', 'material').versionRef('compose_version')
            alias('ui-preview').to('androidx.compose.ui', 'ui-tooling-preview').versionRef('compose_version')
            alias('ui-junit').to('androidx.compose.ui', 'ui-test-junit4').versionRef('compose_version')
            alias('ui-tooling').to('androidx.compose.ui', 'ui-tooling').versionRef('compose_version')

            bundle('suite', ['ui-core', 'material', 'ui-preview'])
        }
    }
```

But it complains about not recognizing `$compose_version`. Is there a way to share the `compose_version` both Root project `build.gradle` and the `settings.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to do it the other way round, by declaring the value in the catalog first

```
    versionCatalogs {
        composeLibs {
            version('compose_version', '1.0.0')
            alias('ui-core').to('androidx.compose.ui', 'ui').versionRef('compose_version')
            alias('material').to('androidx.compose.material', 'material').versionRef('compose_version')
            alias('ui-preview').to('androidx.compose.ui', 'ui-tooling-preview').versionRef('compose_version')
            alias('ui-junit').to('androidx.compose.ui', 'ui-test-junit4').versionRef('compose_version')
            alias('ui-tooling').to('androidx.compose.ui', 'ui-tooling').versionRef('compose_version')

            bundle('suite', ['ui-core', 'material', 'ui-preview'])
        }
    }
```

then share it with the Root's `build.gradle` as below

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = composeLibs.versions.compose.version.get()
    }
    //... some other codes
}
```